# Splitting a list according to a partition of its length

Tags: python, neural-network, partitioning

I have a neural network with n input nodes and k hidden nodes with k << n, I'm trying to take approx(n/k) input nodes to 1 hidden node.  You don't really need to know anything about neural networks, just think edges and nodes.  I have the partition already, it's a list of k numbers which sum to n.  Here is the best algorithm I could come up with

```
k = 0
c = 0
for inputNode in inputNodes:
    Edge(inputNode, hiddenNodes[k])
    c += 1
    if c % partition[k] is 0:
        k += 1
        c = 0
```

I think we can all agree that this is some ugly code, but I spent some time trying to come up with a better way and I couldn't, how can I do this better?  Thanks.

`partition` is a list of numbers which sum to the length of `inputNodes`.  What I'm trying to do is take `partition[0]` input nodes to the first hidden node, `partition[1]` input nodes to the second hidden node, etc, and no sending the same input node to multiple hidden nodes.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense as you make an `Edge` but is never assigned. Can you add some example input and output data?

Comment: Edge is a class which is transient in the sense that it does its job as soon as it's initialized (associating to nodes in a network) and then disappears.

Comment: I get that its a class, but its instantiated and never stored. Also what you are asking seems unclear.

Comment: Why would you create an edge and then throw it away? Are you calling the constructor for side effects? If so, you'll want to redesign that, because that leads to horribly confusing code.

Comment: what is partition[k] ?

Comment: yes probably calling the constructor for side effects, it could probably be done with a function.  Partition[k] is the kth partition in the partition of len(inputNodes).

Comment: All I want is an algorithm that pairs partition[0] input nodes with the first hidden node, partition[1] input nodes with the second hidden note, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over `inputNodes`, it may be clearer to loop over `partition` and use an iterator to draw nodes from `inputNodes` one by one:

```
node_iterator = iter(inputNodes)
for hiddenNode, count in zip(hiddenNodes, partition):
    for _ in xrange(count):
        Edge(next(node_iterator), hiddenNode)
```

Comment: this works, although I had to change line two to `for i, k in enumerate(partition):` and line four to `hiddenNodes[i]`

Comment: @user1378571: Oh, right. I mixed up the indices and values of `partition` for a bit.